# How does Dart treat cascading Futures?

Tags: dart

Say I have this class:

```dart
void main() async {
  final example = ExampleClass();
  await example.waitOne();
  await example.waitOne();
  print('finished');
}

class ExampleClass {
  Future<void> waitOne() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    print('1 second');
  }
}
```

This code works exactly as I expect it to. It's output is as follows:

```
1 second
1 second
finished
```

Then we have this code:

```dart
void main() async {
  final example = ExampleClass();
  await example
    ..waitOne()
    ..waitOne();
  print('finished');
}
```

This code now has cascading operators (..) and the output seems strange:

```
finished
1 second
1 second
```

The code skips the two futures and prints "finished" to the console first, then "1 second" gets printed twice at the same time (like Future#wait would do).

Why does Dart act in this way?

Answer (score 1):

In your example with the cascading operator adding `await` doesn't do anything since the cascade operation doesn't return anything hence there is no future to be awaited and then `finished` is printed right away

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the result of the cascade operator is the original object that you used it on.  That is, for `var result = object..x()..y()..z()`, `result` will be assigned the value of `object`, regardless of what `x`, `y`, or `z` return.  The values returned by `x()`, `y()`, and `z()` are ignored.  It's the equivalent of:

```dart
object.x();
object.y();
object.z();
var result = object;
```

Your case, which involves `Future`s, is no different:

```dart
final example = ExampleClass();
await example
  ..waitOne()
  ..waitOne();
```

So you're doing the equivalent of:

```dart
final example = ExampleClass();
example.waitOne(); // The returned Future is ignored.
example.waitOne(); // The returned Future is ignored.
await example; // Incorrectly using await on a non-Future.
```

(Note that enabling the [`unawaited_future`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html)s and [`await_only_future`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/await_only_futures.html)s lints would catch this mistake.)

To properly wait, you can't use the cascade operator and will need to explicitly `await` the individual operations.  Also see the issue [Prefix `await` is cumbersome to work with.](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/25) which discusses possible changes to the language to support using `await` with member or cascade operators.